# mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

So I have this massive headache inducing query that I need to perform involving **65** form inputs needing to be injected into a database using mysqli prepared statements.

The issue I'm running into is that it says the # of variables I am attempting to call `bind_param` on does not match the # of "s"'s that I am using. **I counted a dozen times** and do not see where I am going wrong here. There are 65 variables, and 65 "s"'s.

Can anyone see something I'm missing? Or am I perhaps using the bind_param method in an incorrect manner?

```
// Preparing our query statement via mysqli which will auto-escape all bad characters to prevent injection
$query3 = 'INSERT INTO datashep_AMS.COMPLETE_APPLICATIONS (
    project_name,
    status,
    funding_requested,
    project_title,
    program,
    county,
    parish,
    name_of_watercourse,
    which_is_a_tributary_of,
    name_of_applicant,
    contact_person_or_project_supervisor,
    relationship_to_organization,
    business_phone,
    home_phone,
    email,
    signature_of_thesis_or_study_supervisor,
    mailing_address,
    postal_code,
    website,
    mailing_address_for_payment,
    hst_registration_no,
    total_cost_dollar,
    total_cost_percent,
    dollar_amount_requested_from_nbwtf,
    percent_amount_requested_from_nbwtf,
    descriptive_summary,
    background_of_organization,
    mandate,
    years_in_existence,
    membership,
    accomplishments,
    previous_project_name,
    previous_project_number,
    previous_project_amount_received_from_nbwtf,
    summary_of_activities,
    summary_of_Results,
    project_title_2,
    reason_and_or_purpose,
    objectives,
    project_description,
    methods,
    equipment_and_materials_required,
    personnel_required,
    proposed_start_date,
    proposed_end_date,
    type_of_data_to_be_stored,
    where_will_it_be_housed,
    monitoring,
    short_term_achievement,
    long_term_achievement,
    previous_studies,
    required_permits,
    consultants,
    short_term_commitment,
    long_term_commitment,
    project_duration,
    project_evaluation,
    promotion_of_project,
    promotion_of_client,
    publication_of_results,
    community_benefits,
    effects_on_traditional_uses,
    possible_changes_in_public_access_to_areas,
    possible_impact_on_wildlife_and_or_environment,
    likelihood_of_future_requests_for_funding,
    list_all_other_funding_sources_for_this_project
) VALUES (
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?
)';

// "Preparing" the query using mysqli->prepare(query) -- which is the equivalent of mysql_real_escape_string -- in other words, it's the SAFE database injection method
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare($query3);

// "Bind_param" == replace all the "?"'s in the aforementioned query with the variables below

$stmt->bind_param("s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s", $project_name, $status, $funding_requested, $project_title, $program, $county, $parish, $name_of_watercourse, $which_is_a_tributary_of, $name_of_applicant, $contact_person_or_project_supervisor, $relationship_to_organization, $business_phone, $home_phone, $email, $signature_of_thesis_or_study_supervisor, $mailing_address, $postal_code, $website, $mailing_address_for_payment, $hst_registration_no, $total_cost_dollar, $total_cost_percent, $dollar_amount_requested_from_nbwtf, $percent_amount_requested_from_nbwtf, $descriptive_summary, $background_of_organization, $mandate, $years_in_existence, $membership, $accomplishments, $previous_project_name, $previous_project_number, $previous_project_amount_received_from_nbwtf, $summary_of_activities, $summary_of_Results, $project_title_2, $reason_and_or_purpose, $objectives, $project_description, $methods, $equipment_and_materials_required, $personnel_required, $proposed_start_date, $proposed_end_date, $type_of_data_to_be_stored, $where_will_it_be_housed, $monitoring, $short_term_commitment, $long_term_achievement, $previous_studies, $required_permits, $consultants, $short_term_commitment, $long_term_commitment, $project_duration, $project_evaluation, $promotion_of_project, $promotion_of_client, $publication_of_results, $community_benefits, $effects_on_traditional_uses, $possible_changes_in_public_access_to_areas, $possible_impact_on_wildlife_and_or_environment, $likelihood_of_future_requests_for_funding, $list_all_other_funding_sources_for_this_project);

// Perform the actual query!
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: where did you get that comma separated format?

Comment: Full disclosure: I'm a beginner so I don't really know of a better way (yet).

Comment: @SamuelStiles I think you really should think about whether you *need* 65 columns in a database table. It might make it more manageable if you had multiple tables and joins.

Comment: @Your Common Sense: What is the current and a better approach for PHP insert query?

Comment: @SuKu for a regular insert query just use a prepared statement

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The number of characters in the type definition string must be equal to the number of placeholders (? marks) in the SQL query.

```
                                                    // three ? marks
$stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO table (one, two, three) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $one, $two, $three);
               // three s characters (and three variables as well)
```

Note that characters in the type definition string should not be separated by commas.

You can see this format demonstrated in the examples on [the manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Answer (score 15):

there are 65 string params so if there are 65 s's you have the correct number. However the errors are appearing because you separated the s's by commas. Instead of `$stmt->bind_param("s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s..."`
it should be

```
$stmt->bind_param("sssssssssssssssss..."
```

This should solve your errors.

Answer (score 3):

The character in the `bind_param` should not be separated by a comma.

If you have to bind two variables do this:

```
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $firstvariable, $secondvariable);
```